# Move a series elements to corresponding different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="left-container">
   <div class="inner">content A here</div>
   <div class="inner">content B here</div>
   <div class="inner">content C here</div>
   <div class="inner">content D here</div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
   <div class="inner"><span>content A2 here</span></div>
   <div class="inner"><span>content B2 here</span></div>
   <div class="inner"><span>content C2 here</span></div>
   <div class="inner"><span>content D3 here</span></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to move the .left-container .inner to the corresponding .right-container .inner, just after the `</span>`, using `appendTo()`, in this way:

```
    jQuery('.left-container .inner').each(function(){

        // save the single reference for each .inner
        var $this = jQuery(this);

        // target destination element
        jQuery('.right-container .inner').each(function(){

            // adding a class to remove it later
            jQuery(this).addClass('not-added');

            // if this destination element has the not-added class
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('not-added')) {

                // append the saved content
                jQuery($this).appendTo(this);

                // and remove the previously added class, so that it won't be targeted on the next iteration
                jQuery(this).removeClass('not-added');
            }
        });
    });
```

The result is:

- All the destination div gets the class added and removed
- All the content is moved to the latest destination div

I can't figure it out, can you help?

Comment: You add the class 'not-added' to the current element and then the next line is an if-statement checking if the current element has the class 'not-added'. Seems like a strange implementation.

Comment: are there always going to be the same number of `inner`s in the left-container as the right container?

Comment: Is this the result you're after https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lyqgw1se/?

Comment: Yes, the number is always the same and there is a 1:1 match in the coloumn. I'm not familiar with jQuery as I usually works server side, so sorry in advance for mistakes

Comment: @j08691 Yes! It should work like that, i'm trying to implement it ;)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer with explanation then

Comment: You are missing . (dot) in front of left-container and right-container class names

Comment: @Vinit sorry not really the case, this is an oversimplified version of my real situation ;) corrected the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the inner divs in the left-container and insert them in the right-container in a variety of ways, but I find it easiest to loop in reverse so that you don't have to worry about managing indexes with what was originally the second element becoming the first once you move the first out of the way etc.

The below code loops over the elements in the order `content D here, content C here, content B here, content A here`, using `.reverse()` and inserts it after the span in the right container using the element's `index` in the left-container div to find the proper position in the right-container div, using `.eq()`

```js
$($(".left-container div").get().reverse()).each(function() {
  $(this).insertAfter($('.right-container span').eq($(this).index()))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-container">
  <div class="inner">content A here</div>
  <div class="inner">content B here</div>
  <div class="inner">content C here</div>
  <div class="inner">content D here</div>
</div>
<div class="right-container">
  <div class="inner"><span>content A2 here</span></div>
  <div class="inner"><span>content B2 here</span></div>
  <div class="inner"><span>content C2 here</span></div>
  <div class="inner"><span>content D3 here</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but In my case there's still a problem: the result is shifted for 1 element. So the result is:

* Content A2 | Content B
* Content B2 | Content C
* Content C2 | Content D
* Content D2 | ...empty...

Why should it behave like that?

Comment: Can you create the problem in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I think it was related to a hidden div I haven't seen in the right column, which altered the reverse count. I've just added a dummy div on the right in the same position and everything seems to work fine now ;)

Comment: I have a matching number of divs now, however I noticed that i have to write like this:

.eq(-jQuery(this).index());

Otherwise the script won't find the matching elements in the right div. To keep the correct order, I had to print the elements in revers order, otherwise I get last_on_left = first_on_right.

Couldn't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

To remove some of the complexity I would do something like this
https://jsbin.com/netaxacitu/edit?html,js,output

```
var copyData = function() {
  jQuery('.right-container .inner').each(function(index){
    var leftMatch = jQuery('.left-container .inner').eq(index).text()
    jQuery(this).text(leftMatch)
    console.log(index)
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to you.

```
jQuery('.right-container .inner').each(function(){
    var elem =  jQuery('.left-container .inner').first();
    elem.appendTo(this);
});
```

But as for me I don't like this style of coding.

Comment: Me neither, it's awful, but I was brought to it, not my work :) anyway your code copies 4 times the first elements for each destination.

Comment: @frafor I prefer to mapping between target and source element. In that case it prevent error in a future when markup will be changed. Something like data-source-id and and data-target-id.

Comment: I prefer to generate the correct code directly from the server, but this is a very specific situation with many non-mantained plugins tied together, and I really don't have time to reverse engineer a thing built like this: if I touch one line of code, it may go down - did happen twice on very banal tasks. That's why I decided to buid a fix on top everything. Not clean, not lean, but it works withouth making the whole shit unstable. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you should have two classes to verify on one hand if left container is already moved and on an other hand, to verify if right container is already added.

In your case, it's normal that it's the last left container which have all the right containers.

I can't test the code but this code should works.

```
jQuery('left-container .inner').each(function(){

    var $left = jQuery(this);

    // target destination element
    jQuery('right-container .inner').each(function(){

        // if this destination element has not added something && moved element has not been moved
        if(!jQuery($left).addClass('already-moved') && !jQuery(this).hasClass('already-added')) {

            // append the saved content
            jQuery($left).appendTo(this);

            jQuery($left).addClass('already-moved');
            jQuery(this).addClass('already-added');
        }
    });
});

jQuery('left-container .inner').removeClass('already-moved');
jQuery('right-container .inner').removeClass('already-added');
```